# How to apply css class based on conditions in SVG code?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, svg

I am implementing svg code through *ngFor loop in angular:

I want to add css to the particular svg path only and that should be based upon conditions.

Here is a piece of my code :

HTML :

```
<svg class="height-width" version="1.1" id="svg2" height="695.70178" width="611.85999"
        mapsvg:geoViewBox="68.184010 37.084109 97.418146 6.753659">
        <path class="select" *ngFor="let item of myData" [attr.d]="item.d" [attr.title]="item.title"
            [attr.id]="item.id" />
</svg>
```

```js
myData = [
    {
      "id": "SG-01", "title": "Central Singapore", "myColor": "#000", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 431.09042,77.54 1.18,0.42 1.92,0.51 1.44,1.59 1.85,1.34 1.09,1.59 0.75,1.37 0.09,1.28 0.99,1.55 2.04,2.04 1.27,1.2 1.42,0.7 1.26,0.99 1.68,0.52 0.92,0.08 0.33,0.75 0.92,0.42 1.13,0.09 0.67,-1.26 1.43,-1.34 1.01,0 2.01,0.08 1.34,0.33 2.27,1.51 1.59,1.01 1.62,0.55 1.58,0.47 1.91,0.47 2.79,0.03 1.96,0.44 1.26,0.09 1.11,0.62 0.88,0.79 1.03,0.91 1.06,0.65 1.58,1.34 -0.3,0.29 -1.6,2.44 -3.55,5.42 -2.9,2.15 -3.09,1.5 -2.53,1.69 -1.5,1.78 -0.37,4.87 -0.66,1.12 -0.66,1.59 -0.4,1.84 -0.17,0.78 -2.43,3.84 -2.53,1.03 -2.43,1.22 -0.09,6.18 -1.31,1.78 -1.59,0.84 -0.13,1.68 -1.74,2.93 -1.9,3.42 -0.95,3.61 -0.95,4.18 -1.33,5.13 -1.71,4.36 -1.84,3.15 -3.48,-0.21 -4.58,-0.86 -3.29,-0.57 -3.58,-0.29 -3.29,1.57 -2.57,4.14 -1.72,4.44 -1.57,6.15 -2.57,4.57 -2.72,4.44 -0.14,5.87 2.15,2.28 2,4.29 1,3.86 0.14,3.01 -1.86,1.86 -5.15,0.29 -3.29,1.42 0,3.72 4.15,0.14 5.15,0.86 3.72,0.86 0.72,2.86 0.14,4.44 1.86,4.57 2.28,3.86 1.72,0.86 4.58,1.43 3.29,1.43 2.57,3.86 4.29,3 0.57,4.87 1.71,2.58 -0.38,1.35 -0.48,1.66 -2.43,1 -1.43,0.86 -1.29,2.29 -3.72,3 -1,3.43 0.43,1.43 1,1.72 0.71,1.57 0.71,2.72 -0.5,1.08 0.09,0.75 0.14,1.55 -0.2,1.09 -0.54,1.56 -0.75,1.43 -1.5,1.38 -1.78,1.39 -1.06,0.62 -0.77,0.46 -0.14,0.59 -0.71,1.59 -1.18,0.64 -1.7,1.87 -1.64,1.58 -0.33,2 -0.39,3.26 0.36,3.02 0.48,2.17 0.83,2.68 -0.07,1.77 -0.07,2.24 -2.24,0.61 -1.63,-0.05 -2.38,-0.07 -2.58,-0.14 -2.04,-0.34 -1.97,0.14 -3.6,-0.27 -0.95,3.4 -0.49,1.07 -0.33,2.4 -0.2,1.49 0.26,3.35 0.65,0.59 1.26,3.18 2.04,0.2 1.14,-2.67 1.72,-2.57 1.28,-2.43 0.88,-1.43 0.34,-1.83 1.49,-0.07 1.97,0.14 1.43,0.54 1.29,0.75 2.06,0.58 3.26,1.45 3.38,2.17 2.54,2.29 2.42,2.78 1.21,1.69 -0.24,1.93 -17,13.37 -1.9,0 -1.51,-0.47 -2.38,-0.72 -2.62,-0.95 -0.76,-0.64 -0.68,-0.27 0.07,-0.95 0.61,-0.41 0,-1.02 -0.88,-0.54 -1.54,0.14 -0.3,-0.19 -1.35,-0.72 -1.43,-0.4 -1.43,-0.64 -2.53,2.03 0.19,0.99 0.03,15.49 -1.09,0.88 0.2,1.29 1.84,1.93 -0.56,0.4 -0.87,-0.79 -1.43,-1.67 -1.67,-1.75 -1.58,-1.58 -1.83,-2.06 -1.91,-1.75 -1.11,0.08 -0.63,0.56 -0.59,1.3 -1.08,0.99 1.43,1.63 1.15,1.43 0.95,1.22 0.14,1.02 -0.68,0 -2.83,-3.23 -1.51,-1.18 -1.43,-0.95 -0.82,-1.29 -1.02,-1.02 -0.88,-0.68 -1.07,-1.17 -3.89,-0.25 -9.5,-0.12 -0.67,0.49 -1.75,0.96 -2.06,1.19 -3.73,2.3 -1.68,1.17 -1.48,0.24 -1.76,1.05 -8.09,0 -0.24,-1.19 -0.88,-0.08 -0.63,-0.47 -1.44,-0.13 -0.29,0.63 -0.57,-0.12 -0.03,-0.57 1.17,-0.86 -2.12,-1.4 -0.43,1.23 -1.15,1.69 -1.01,-0.39 -1.19,-1.11 -0.95,-0.95 0.41,-0.7 1.26,-1.4 -1.09,-0.73 -0.78,-0.07 -1.7,-0.83 -2.47,-2.09 -1.71,-3.23 -0.95,-3.04 0.76,-3.04 2.28,-3.23 1.9,-1.9 3.04,-2.66 -0.38,-3.42 -1.52,-2.28 -4.56,0.19 -3.99,-0.19 -2.85,-1.14 -4.18,-0.19 -2.28,1.52 -4.18,-1.33 -4.18,-3.6 -1.71,-3.23 -0.76,-5.5 -0.76,-4.94 -0.76,-3.42 -1.33,-3.42 -2.66,-1.9 -1.52,-3.99 1.33,-3.04 1.9,-3.42 0.57,-3.41 2.3,1.78 1.95,1.71 1.47,1.47 1.71,-0.24 0.73,-3.42 0.49,-1.95 0.73,-2.69 0,-2.69 -0.24,-2.69 0.73,-2.69 2.44,-3.91 2.69,-3.91 2.2,-2.44 1.71,-2.2 2.2,-0.49 3.18,-1.22 2.44,-3.18 0,-2.93 1.22,-3.91 -0.49,-3.67 1.22,-2.44 2.2,-1.47 1.71,-2.2 -0.49,-3.18 -2.44,-0.49 -2.93,0 -3.18,-1.95 -3.91,-4.15 -3.91,-3.42 -2.44,-2.69 -3.91,-2.69 -0.98,-4.15 1.47,-4.4 2.93,-3.67 2.93,-1.71 2.44,-3.42 1.22,-4.15 5.13,-4.4 3.91,-2.93 3.18,-2.44 1.96,-4.64 1.95,-5.86 2.81,-4.53 1.45,-5.8 0,0 -1.57,-2.62 -1.71,-2.2 -0.98,-3.42 -0.73,-4.4 0.49,-5.62 0,-6.6 -1.47,-5.86 -2.93,-3.91 -2.44,-4.4 -1.22,-2.2 1.71,-2.2 3.91,-0.73 4.4,-0.49 3.42,-2.69 3.42,-4.64 2.93,-5.86 2.44,-6.11 1.47,-4.89 1.71,-5.62 2.93,-3.91 3.91,-1.71 6.35,0.73 2.93,1.22 3.18,3.42 1.95,3.18 3.18,3.67 4.64,0.49 4.15,-2.2 5,-0.12 0,0 1.54,-0.7 2.1,-0.85 1.4,-0.14 1.58,0.02 -0.47,1.31 -0.38,1.03 -0.84,1.41 -1.41,2.06 -1.5,1.31 -2.44,2.16 -2.53,1.31 -1.6,0.56 -2.25,1.41 -3.47,0.84 -3.47,1.31 -2.82,0.56 -3.08,0.66 -4.33,0.47 -1.5,1.13 -1.78,0.85 -0.47,2.16 -1.88,1.22 -0.66,1.13 0.84,1.69 0.56,1.31 0.09,1.88 0.19,0.94 0.84,0.47 1.13,-0.47 1.52,-1.66 1.16,-1.37 1.48,-2.16 0.74,-2.53 0.55,-1.19 2.39,0 5.63,0.19 5.73,-0.47 3.1,-1.31 2.06,-1.69 0.38,-0.16 3.23,-1.38 3.48,-0.73 1.31,-1.59 2.32,-0.84 0.92,-1.13 1.12,-1.74 0.77,-1.3 1.14,-0.97 0.75,-0.67 1.15,-1.44 1.48,-1.34 0.49,-1.55 0.21,-2.18 0.63,-1.69 0.92,-1.2 1.2,-1.34 1.2,-0.63 0.56,-0.28 0,-1.2 1.06,-1.76 1.06,-2.99 1.76,-1.97 0.92,-0.42 1.72,-0.57 0.59,-0.32 1.26,0 0.05,-0.09 0.81,-0.57 1.56,-0.31 1.17,-0.16 1.7,0.19 1.32,-0.45 1.08,0.1 z m 46.68,14.47 -1.15,0.99 -0.66,0.08 -0.82,-0.41 -1.65,-0.08 -2.47,0.17 -3.3,-0.33 -2.8,-0.41 -1.73,-0.74 -1.65,-0.99 -1.15,-0.74 -1.9,-0.41 -1.73,-0.49 -0.17,-0.66 0.66,-1.24 1.48,-1.07 1.15,-1.48 1.48,-2.31 1.81,-1.9 1.57,-2.47 1.57,-0.08 1.4,0.91 3.13,1.81 1.98,1.15 2.06,1.4 2.39,1.57 1.48,1.24 0.82,1.4 -0.17,0.91 -0.5,0.91 -0.33,1.65 -0.8,1.62 z m -22.75,-6.02 -1.57,1.81 -5.03,-0.08 -1.73,-1.15 -2.14,-1.65 -1.57,-1.73 -0.99,-1.24 -0.74,-1.24 -1.32,-0.99 -2.14,-1.57 -2.97,-2.39 -1.98,-1.15 -0.99,-0.66 0.08,-1.81 0.99,-1.57 2.39,-1.4 2.72,-2.23 1.81,-1.15 1.4,-0.66 4.86,-0.25 2.06,0.99 4.86,2.64 3.87,2.89 4.12,2.8 0.91,0.82 -0.08,1.15 -3.3,4.7 -2.14,2.72 -1.38,2.4 z"
    },
    {
      "id": "SG-02", "title": "North East", "myColor": "#000", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 532.93042,110.3 1.26,1.05 1.33,1.02 0.49,1.15 0.1,1.4 -0.21,0.8 -0.94,0.25 -1.05,-0.31 -0.49,-1.02 -1.01,-0.85 -1.43,-1.43 -0.81,-0.47 -1.18,-0.67 -1.26,-0.72 -0.87,0 -0.74,0.81 -0.42,0.99 -0.52,-0.01 -0.67,-0.42 0.25,-0.98 0.6,-0.7 0.07,-0.98 -0.29,-1.41 -1.37,-1.07 -2.25,-1.76 -1.37,-0.52 -0.97,-1.13 -0.32,-1.68 -0.56,-1.26 -0.6,-0.56 -0.77,-1.26 -1.2,-0.68 -0.65,-0.62 -1.19,-0.28 -0.41,-1.03 -0.82,-0.76 -1.25,-0.72 -1.09,-1 -0.39,-0.98 0.07,-1.01 1.09,-0.38 0.94,0.1 0.91,0.77 1.05,0.84 1.05,1.44 0.56,1.54 1.05,0.52 2.14,0.88 1.09,0.46 1.4,0.74 1.01,1.12 1.64,1.48 1.54,1.96 1.26,1.54 1.58,1.51 1.22,1.26 1.72,1.72 1.68,1.32 z m -26.77,-17.66 0.42,2.19 -0.16,1.68 -0.42,1.59 0,1.51 0.5,1.26 2.54,1.19 4.18,3.8 5.88,5.7 3.61,2.65 4.94,3.42 -1.14,2.65 -5.32,3.23 0.38,2.28 1.32,1.6 2.48,-1.79 4.75,-2.66 3.23,-1.52 3.23,-0.38 2.66,1.9 2.47,2.47 2.28,3.6 1.9,4.18 2.28,3.8 2.85,1.14 3.61,1.71 3.19,3.11 1.43,1.51 1.85,1.42 1.76,0.08 1.43,1.26 1.26,0.5 0.92,0.84 1.18,0.75 1.51,0.08 1.85,1.01 1.93,-0.08 1.43,0.42 0.58,1.51 -0.25,1.18 1.09,0.58 0.08,-0.75 0.76,-1.59 1,0 0.92,0 0.67,1 1.09,-0.59 0.75,-0.25 1.09,0.59 1.51,0.25 2.35,0 1.09,-0.92 1.68,-0.25 1.51,-0.42 1.34,-0.42 1.26,-0.25 1.51,0.51 1.51,1.17 0.97,0.27 1.66,0.24 0.49,-1.81 0,-1.45 0.67,-1.57 1.34,-0.45 0.55,-0.96 1.01,-0.7 0.46,3 0.95,2.85 2.28,2.85 3.04,2.66 2.28,1.33 1.14,3.23 -0.76,3.61 -3.04,1.52 -1.33,1.52 -2.28,3.8 -3.61,3.61 -2.09,2.47 -2.66,2.09 -3.42,2.66 -1.52,0.95 0.57,2.85 1.71,1.9 1.14,3.99 0.38,4.18 -0.38,4.37 -3.42,1.33 -5.51,1.14 -2.85,1.33 -3.23,2.28 -3.42,3.23 -3.23,2.47 -3.42,3.04 -4.18,1.14 -3.04,0 -2.28,-2.09 -2.85,-1.9 -3.23,0.19 -6.83,0.57 -5.32,0.57 -3.99,-0.95 -3.61,-0.76 -3.42,-0.38 -1.04,2.97 1.56,0.46 2.51,0.24 -0.04,0.71 0.42,1.62 1.24,0.19 0.41,2.06 1.46,0.09 0.94,0.76 1.42,1.6 0.2,1.53 0.57,0.46 0.03,1.2 -1.51,1.89 -2.85,0.76 -4.56,0 -2.85,1.71 -2.85,2.47 -2.47,0.76 -2.09,0.38 -2.28,2.47 1.33,2.85 -1.9,1.52 -2.09,3.04 1.9,2.09 1.71,1.14 0,2.85 -0.38,1.9 -1.52,1.52 -5.51,-0.19 -5.13,0.57 -5.7,0.76 -5.32,0.76 -3.04,-0.38 -1.71,-2.28 -1.14,-3.61 1.9,-3.04 0.19,-3.04 -3.23,-2.09 -1.33,-3.04 -2.28,-3.42 -4.56,-4.37 -3.99,-3.23 -3.61,-4.37 -3.99,-1.52 -2.66,-2.47 -2.09,-2.47 0.57,-3.23 -0.95,-4.18 -1.9,-2.09 -6.65,-0.38 -3.23,-1.14 -3.04,-1.14 -3.42,-0.76 -2.47,-3.23 -1.14,-2.28 -0.19,-3.8 -2.28,-2.85 -3.42,-2.47 -1.9,-3.61 0,-5.71 1.33,-4.18 1.9,-4.18 0.82,-1.41 1.84,-3.15 1.71,-4.36 1.33,-5.13 0.95,-4.18 0.95,-3.61 1.9,-3.42 1.74,-2.93 0.13,-1.68 1.59,-0.84 1.31,-1.78 0.09,-6.18 2.43,-1.22 2.53,-1.03 2.43,-3.84 0.56,-2.62 0.66,-1.59 0.66,-1.12 0.37,-4.87 1.5,-1.78 2.53,-1.69 3.09,-1.5 2.9,-2.15 5.15,-7.86 0.3,-0.29 1.12,-1.02 0.39,-1.76 3.04,-1.52 4.56,-1.41 1.04,-1.05 1.76,0.08 0.21,-1.31 0.8,-0.79 1.43,-0.34 -0.36,-1.69 0.96,-0.98 0.84,-0.85 0.75,-0.77 0.31,-1.54 0.86,-0.9 1.01,0 2.74,-0.18 0.81,-0.79 0.81,-0.79 1.18,-0.25 1.26,0.59 0.75,0.67 0.08,1.43 -0.59,0.84 -0.67,0.59 -0.09,1.09 1.09,0.08 0.33,0.76 0.33,1.17 0.76,0.92 0.27,1.7 z"
    },
    {
      "id": "SG-03", "title": "North West", "myColor": "#000", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 411.83042,35.48 0.98,0 1.03,1.03 0.38,1.13 0.66,0.84 0.75,0.75 0.84,0.47 0.38,0.28 1.03,0.85 0.47,1.41 0.28,1.5 0.56,0.84 0.66,1.03 1.03,0.75 0.56,0.75 0.28,0.84 0.94,0.56 0.84,1.22 0.09,1.78 0.66,0.94 0.47,0.84 0.19,1.13 -0.75,0.66 -1.31,-0.38 -0.47,-1.03 -0.56,-0.47 -0.47,-1.03 -0.66,-0.75 -0.94,-1.22 -0.75,-0.75 -0.75,-0.94 -0.75,-1.03 -0.66,-0.47 -0.28,-1.22 -0.75,-0.94 -0.38,-0.94 0.19,-1.13 0.38,-0.56 -0.38,-1.03 -0.66,-0.66 -0.47,-0.66 0.19,-0.66 -0.56,-0.47 -0.94,-0.56 -0.28,-1.22 0.09,-0.84 -1.16,-0.64 z m 0,0 -0.15,0 -0.19,-0.19 0.34,0.19 z m -65.75,-29.71 -1.22,1.31 -0.66,1.41 -0.75,1.69 1.22,1.41 1.22,-0.56 1.22,-0.84 0.66,-1.13 1.22,-1.69 0.32,-0.17 0.81,-0.3 0.94,0.19 0.1,0.93 0.09,0.38 0.28,1.22 0.38,0.84 0.94,0.38 0,0.19 -0.02,0.05 0.01,0.29 0.01,-0.02 0,0.53 -0.56,0.84 -0.94,1.22 -0.94,1.13 0.84,0.75 1.5,-0.09 0.66,-1.69 1.22,-1.78 1.41,-0.56 0.85,-0.94 0.94,-2.07 1.69,-2.53 1.13,-1.88 1.6,-0.25 1.48,0.81 4.29,2.5 2.72,1.97 -0.28,0.94 -0.66,1.03 -0.94,1.6 -0.38,1.13 -0.66,0.84 -0.38,1.03 0.09,0.75 0.56,0.66 1.03,0.56 1.31,-0.47 1.03,-1.31 0.56,-1.41 0.84,-1.13 0.47,-1.03 0.47,-1.41 2.53,0 1.2,0.75 1.68,0.84 1.34,0.84 1.34,1.34 2.31,1.39 1.21,0.96 1.33,0.63 1.87,1.8 1.85,1.34 2.27,1.68 2.01,0.84 1.43,0.67 1.75,0.62 1.27,1.31 0.58,1.26 1.09,1.34 0.81,1.62 -0.18,2.41 0.18,0.13 0.47,1.13 0.85,1.31 0.94,0.84 0.84,0.94 0.82,0.96 0.3,0.07 0.56,1.13 0.47,0.94 0.47,1.41 0.38,1.78 1.03,2.53 -0.05,0.03 0.8,0.72 0.75,0.75 0.38,0.75 0.47,1.12 0.1,0.01 1.22,1.03 1.13,1.69 0.45,1.71 0.92,0.92 2.01,2.26 1.26,2.04 0.18,1.99 0.47,1.03 -0.51,2.43 -0.52,0.67 -1.13,0.84 -1.22,1.03 -1.13,0.38 -0.28,0.47 0.38,0.56 0.28,0.56 0.66,0.19 -0.66,0.75 -1.03,0.19 -1.03,0.09 -0.84,1.03 -0.47,1.97 -0.56,0.94 -0.66,1.5 -1.31,0.28 -1.03,0.75 0,1.31 -0.19,1.78 -0.38,2.44 -0.84,1.22 -0.47,1.31 -0.94,0.75 -0.6,0.54 0.04,0.45 -0.84,1.03 -0.66,0.84 -0.47,0.75 -0.28,1.6 -0.56,1.41 -0.86,1.69 -1.58,-0.02 -1.4,0.14 -2.1,0.85 -1.54,0.7 -5,0.12 -4.15,2.2 -4.64,-0.49 -3.18,-3.67 -1.95,-3.18 -3.18,-3.42 -2.93,-1.22 -6.35,-0.73 -3.91,1.71 -2.93,3.91 -3.18,10.51 -2.44,6.11 -2.93,5.86 -3.42,4.64 -3.42,2.69 -4.4,0.49 -3.91,0.73 -1.71,2.2 3.66,6.6 2.93,3.91 1.47,5.86 0,6.6 -0.49,5.62 0.73,4.4 0.98,3.42 1.71,2.2 1.57,2.62 -1.45,5.8 -2.81,4.53 -1.95,5.86 -1.96,4.64 -3.18,2.44 -3.91,2.93 -5.13,4.4 -1.22,4.15 -2.44,3.42 -2.93,1.71 -2.93,3.67 -1.47,4.4 0.98,4.15 3.91,2.69 2.44,2.69 3.91,3.42 3.91,4.15 3.18,1.95 2.93,0 2.44,0.49 0.49,3.18 -1.71,2.2 -2.2,1.47 -1.22,2.44 0.49,3.67 -1.22,3.91 0,2.93 -2.44,3.18 -3.18,1.22 -2.2,0.49 -1.71,2.2 -2.2,2.44 -2.69,3.91 -2.44,3.91 -0.73,2.69 0.24,2.69 0,2.69 -0.73,2.69 -0.49,1.95 -0.73,3.42 -1.71,0.24 -1.47,-1.47 -1.95,-1.71 -2.3,-1.78 -0.95,-3.42 -4.75,-0.94 -5.13,-2.85 -4.37,-2.66 -4.18,-3.04 -2.09,-2.28 -5.7,0 -4.37,-2.47 -5.32,-4.18 -4.18,-4.75 -6.27,-3.99 -4.94,-3.99 -2.09,-2.28 -1.9,-2.85 -0.57,-2.09 0,-6.08 3.8,0.75 4.18,0 3.23,-0.95 3.04,-2.28 2.66,-1.9 3.23,-0.76 0.57,-4.36 4.37,0 3.99,-0.57 2.1,-2.28 -0.57,-4.36 -2.28,-2.28 -2.66,-1.52 -2.85,-1.33 -4.18,-5.13 -5.51,-6.08 -3.99,-5.5 -0.76,-5.7 -0.57,-9.11 -0.57,-5.32 -2.28,-3.6 -2.85,-5.32 -1.33,-5.7 -2.47,-6.08 -1.71,-5.31 -1.9,-4.75 -3.61,-3.8 -4.18,-6.26 -3.04,-6.26 -1.33,-8.55 -0.95,-5.5 2.66,-5.51 2.28,-3.23 -0.57,-7.6 0,-5.31 0.76,-8.55 5.51,-5.31 4.37,-5.13 2.28,-3.61 -0.38,-6.08 -1.52,-4.75 -0.41,-2.93 1.46,-0.06 1.06,-0.23 0.26,0.47 0.15,-0.53 0.75,-0.66 1.03,-0.66 0.66,-0.47 0.38,-0.84 0.56,-1.41 0.56,-0.56 0.75,-1.03 0.56,-1.69 0.47,-0.94 0.56,-0.94 1.31,-0.47 2.91,-0.19 0.09,-1.03 -0.47,-0.66 0.09,-1.13 0.56,-1.31 0.75,-1.03 1.69,-1.03 1.13,-0.84 0.66,-0.84 1.78,-0.75 1.64,-0.49 0.1,-0.17 0.47,0 0.48,-0.37 0.65,-0.53 0.8,-0.44 1.03,-0.12 1.05,-0.25 0.85,-0.57 0.29,-0.2 1.77,-0.12 2.27,-1.42 0.02,-0.14 0.21,0.03 1.13,-0.66 2.06,-1.22 3.29,-2.35 2.16,-2.06 2.25,-1.78 2.53,-1.22 1.88,-1.5 3.66,-2.72 1.41,-0.47 1.88,-1.03 3,-1.88 2.91,-2.35 2.53,-1.6 1.17,-0.82 0.83,-0.27 0.44,-0.63 0.37,-0.26 1.6,-0.75 1.6,-0.56 1.53,-0.9 0,0 0.01,-0.01 0.05,-0.03 0.02,-0.04 1.1,-1.02 1.34,-1.93 1.57,-0.72 2.35,-0.09 1.18,-0.42 2.64,-0.4 1.5,-0.47 2.06,0 2.36,-0.22 2.44,-0.62 3.69,-0.05 2.85,-0.42 2.77,-0.08 2.1,0 2.77,0.25 1.68,0.42 1.6,1.01 1.68,0.67 0.3,0.73 0.22,0.35 -0.59,0.21 -1.13,0.38 -1.5,0.47 -1.61,1.03 z"
    },
    {
      "id": "SG-04", "title": "South East", "myColor": "#000", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 633.52042,131.77 2.21,0.72 1.31,-0.07 3.15,1.39 2.5,0.66 2.46,0.78 2.69,0.34 1.23,0.78 1.79,0.34 0.1,0.17 2.26,1.09 1.55,1.09 2,1.09 2.46,2.37 2.55,2.19 2.46,3.65 1.55,2.64 0.55,2.46 1.09,2.46 0.82,2.28 0.46,6.47 -0.27,3.83 -0.37,2.92 0.09,0.07 -0.09,10.51 2.64,0.18 2.83,1.18 2.46,1.55 -2,5.1 -3.28,7.56 -4.45,10.68 -3.74,8.68 -2.73,6.65 -4.28,9.11 -3.83,9.3 -1.37,3.28 -0.27,1.82 -0.64,2.19 1.37,2.1 2.28,0.55 2.1,0.18 2.28,-0.36 3.37,-0.64 2.28,-0.18 1.37,-0.36 1.64,-0.27 1.73,-0.73 2.92,-0.73 1.64,0.18 1.82,0.55 2.19,0.73 1.73,0.91 1.28,0.82 1.46,1.09 1.37,0.46 2,0.36 1.28,0.82 2.19,0.64 1.91,1.37 0.04,1.19 0.1,2.75 -0.43,1.94 -0.65,0.86 -0.02,0.03 -0.05,0 -1.05,0.96 -2.45,0.65 -2.09,0.65 -1.91,0.43 -2.52,0.83 -2.41,1.19 -1.94,1.01 -1.87,0.47 -1.76,0.72 -2.09,0.72 -1.62,0.65 -1.08,0.36 -3.09,0.31 -5.16,0.61 -3.77,-0.2 -3.18,-1.77 -3.96,-1.91 -6.36,-2.31 -6.31,1.39 -3.82,1.34 -1.27,-6.35 -0.79,-1.37 5.73,-12.81 -1.2,-0.21 -2.26,5.52 -2.12,3.82 -1.03,3.71 -2.12,0.5 -4.67,-0.28 -2.58,0.82 -0.99,0.5 -0.99,0.57 -0.64,-0.28 -0.15,-1.38 -1.23,-0.08 -0.85,1.56 -1.33,-0.41 -4,0.1 -1.37,0 -0.68,0.68 -1.25,-0.57 -0.8,0 -1.14,0.46 -0.57,0.57 -2.28,0 -0.68,0.8 -1.25,0.34 -1.14,0 -1.37,0.68 -2.61,0 -0.06,0.21 -1.74,-0.24 -1.35,0.32 -0.63,0.79 -1.27,0 -1.28,0.67 -0.95,0.71 -1.27,0.16 -0.24,0.71 -1.51,-0.08 -2.14,0.56 -1.27,1.11 -2.01,1.21 -3.3,0.57 -2.28,0.46 -2.16,0.8 -1.48,0.91 -2.05,0.23 -1.48,0.46 -1.82,0.46 -2.62,0.57 -1.14,0.57 -1.71,1.25 -1.25,0.68 -3.19,0.34 -3.41,0.68 -2.56,-0.61 -1.31,1.98 -1.61,-0.75 -0.1,-0.01 -1.48,-0.31 -1.45,0.95 -1.75,-0.08 -2.22,0.56 -1.19,1.19 -1.51,-0.16 -1.19,0.08 -1.96,-0.37 -1.25,0.57 -1.37,0.46 -1.59,0.34 -1.29,1.21 -2.37,0.5 -1.19,0.16 -1.75,0 -1.19,0.4 -0.95,0.95 -1.03,-0.08 -1.93,-0.21 -0.29,0.69 -1.9,0.4 -1.87,0.21 -1.93,0.57 -1.2,1.45 -1.59,0.32 -1.34,0.58 -0.88,1.24 -2.06,0.08 -1.82,0.56 -1.43,0.24 -2.46,0.08 -1.73,0.26 -2.57,0.43 -3.07,1.37 -2.5,0.57 -2.96,0.91 -2.31,1.58 -1.59,1.79 -2.38,1.59 -3.41,1.45 -1.62,1.11 -1.62,0.77 -1.54,0.94 -2.2,0.84 -1.13,-0.77 -0.77,0.08 -1.71,0.85 -2.22,2.22 -1.02,1.28 -1.19,0.51 -0.85,0 -0.94,-0.09 -1.28,0.6 -0.39,1.02 -1.35,1.27 -1.19,1.27 -2.14,1.9 -1.76,-0.43 -1.2,0 -1.19,0.85 -1.2,1.2 -1.28,1.28 -0.7,1.3 -1.34,0.58 -0.5,1.32 -1.04,-0.38 -1.37,-1.37 -0.99,-1.66 -1.83,-1.33 -1.42,-2 -1.11,-1.51 -1.03,-1.59 -1.27,-1.98 -0.95,-1.11 -0.7,-2.39 -1.45,-3.33 -1.79,-3.16 -0.07,-5.04 0.31,-1.01 1.22,-0.18 0.85,0.77 3.5,0.17 1.28,-0.43 1.02,-0.34 1.45,-0.34 2.9,0 1.28,0.6 2.65,0.26 1.02,-1.11 -0.27,-1.34 -0.5,-0.71 -1.44,-0.82 -1.82,-0.16 -1.59,-1.59 -1.51,-1.59 -0.21,-4.11 -1.53,-1.35 -2.23,0.06 0.75,-1.43 0.54,-1.56 0.2,-1.09 -0.14,-1.55 -0.09,-0.75 0.5,-1.08 -0.71,-2.72 -0.71,-1.57 -1,-1.72 -0.43,-1.43 1,-3.43 2,-1.57 1.72,-1.43 1.29,-2.29 1.43,-0.86 2.43,-1 0.86,-3 -1.72,-2.57 -0.57,-4.86 -4.29,-3 -2.58,-3.86 -3.29,-1.43 -4.58,-1.43 -1.72,-0.86 -2.29,-3.86 -1.86,-4.58 -0.14,-4.43 -0.72,-2.86 -3.72,-0.86 -5.15,-0.86 -4.15,-0.14 0,-3.72 3.29,-1.43 5.15,-0.29 1.86,-1.86 -0.14,-3 -1,-3.86 -2,-4.29 -2.15,-2.29 0.14,-5.86 2.72,-4.43 2.58,-4.58 1.57,-6.15 1.72,-4.43 2.57,-4.15 3.29,-1.57 3.58,0.29 3.29,0.57 4.58,0.86 3.48,0.21 -0.82,1.41 -1.9,4.18 -1.33,4.18 0,5.7 1.9,3.61 3.42,2.47 2.28,2.85 0.19,3.8 1.14,2.28 2.47,3.23 3.42,0.76 3.04,1.14 3.23,1.14 6.65,0.38 1.9,2.09 0.95,4.18 -0.57,3.23 2.09,2.47 2.66,2.47 3.99,1.52 3.61,4.37 3.99,3.23 4.56,4.37 2.28,3.42 1.33,3.04 3.23,2.09 -0.19,3.04 -1.9,3.04 1.14,3.61 1.71,2.28 3.04,0.38 5.32,-0.76 5.7,-0.76 5.13,-0.57 5.51,0.19 1.52,-1.52 0.38,-1.9 0,-2.85 -1.71,-1.14 -1.9,-2.09 2.09,-3.04 1.9,-1.52 -1.33,-2.85 2.28,-2.47 2.09,-0.38 2.47,-0.76 2.85,-2.47 2.85,-1.71 4.56,0 2.85,-0.76 1.51,-1.89 -0.03,-1.2 -0.57,-0.46 -0.2,-1.53 -1.42,-1.6 -0.94,-0.76 -1.46,-0.09 -0.41,-2.06 -1.24,-0.19 -0.42,-1.62 0.04,-0.71 -2.51,-0.24 -1.56,-0.46 1.04,-2.97 3.42,0.38 3.61,0.76 3.99,0.95 5.32,-0.57 6.83,-0.57 3.23,-0.19 2.85,1.9 2.28,2.09 3.04,0 4.18,-1.14 3.42,-3.04 3.23,-2.47 3.42,-3.23 3.23,-2.28 2.85,-1.33 5.51,-1.14 3.42,-1.33 0.38,-4.37 -0.38,-4.18 -1.14,-3.99 -1.71,-1.9 -0.57,-2.85 1.52,-0.95 3.42,-2.66 2.66,-2.09 2.09,-2.47 3.61,-3.61 2.28,-3.8 1.33,-1.52 3.04,-1.52 0.76,-3.61 -1.14,-3.23 -2.28,-1.33 -3.04,-2.66 -2.28,-2.85 -0.95,-2.85 -0.46,-3 1.66,-1.43 1.02,-1.74 0.56,-0.54 0.55,-0.31 2.17,-2.39 1.78,-1.53 0.57,-1.94 1.68,-0.78 0.78,-1.23 1.23,-0.45 2.01,-0.56 2.79,-0.39 1.59,0.39 2.67,-0.78 2.22,1.03 1.37,0 1.91,-0.85 1.3,-0.32 1.5,-0.15 1.47,0.02 z m -58.64,-11.89 -0.53,0.15 -0.6,-0.08 -0.75,-0.45 -1.88,-1.96 -2.11,-1.88 -0.08,-1.05 -0.98,-1.28 0.68,-0.15 0.98,0.75 0.98,0.15 0.9,0.45 1.05,0.45 1.05,0.38 -0.08,0.83 0.15,0.6 0.45,0.38 0.45,0.68 -0.3,0.53 0,0.6 0.53,0.6 0.09,0.3 z m -9.4,-10.23 -0.38,0.38 -0.83,-0.3 -0.53,-0.83 -1.05,-1.05 -1.28,-1.05 0.68,-0.38 0.3,0.15 0.98,0.15 0.68,0.45 0.68,0.68 0.38,1.05 0.37,0.75 z m 128.23,-11.75 -1.58,0.23 -1.18,-0.4 -1.3,-0.79 -1.64,-1.35 -1.02,-0.79 -1.07,-1.35 -0.68,-1.47 -0.4,-1.35 -0.51,-1.41 0.62,-0.85 0.56,-0.68 0.68,-0.96 0.9,-1.19 0.39,-1.24 0.62,-1.3 0.51,-0.85 0.06,-0.85 -0.39,-0.45 0.23,-0.56 0.4,-0.45 0.51,0.34 0.17,1.13 0.23,1.07 0.56,0.51 0.51,0.62 0.34,0.85 1.52,0.34 1.52,0.23 1.47,0.56 1.3,0.51 0.62,1.41 0.96,1.13 1.41,1.75 0.68,1.64 0,1.3 -0.34,1.35 -0.34,1.18 -0.79,0.9 -1.35,0.11 -1.58,0.34 -1.52,0.4 -1.08,0.39 z m -115.15,-8.7 0.7,0.6 11.54,0 1.61,-0.7 1.4,-0.7 1.2,-0.4 7.52,0.1 1.2,-0.4 3.52,0 3.11,0.5 3.01,0.5 2.31,0.7 2.01,0.4 1.2,0.4 1.6,0.1 1,-1.2 1.91,0.3 2.01,0.4 1.91,0 1.5,-0.6 1,-0.4 1,0.1 0.4,1.5 0.3,0.6 1.3,-0.2 0.9,-0.8 0.6,-0.5 2.31,-0.3 0.4,1 0.8,0.5 0.8,1 -0.1,1 0.3,1.81 0.4,1 -0.1,1.4 0.3,1.4 -0.4,0.9 -0.6,1.6 0.2,2.01 1.1,0.9 0.6,0.6 0.6,0.3 -0.3,0.7 -1.1,-0.3 -1.71,-0.5 -2.31,0.3 -1.1,0.7 -1.4,-0.6 -1.91,0.6 -1.2,0.5 -0.8,0.4 -2.01,0 -1,-0.5 -1.61,-0.4 -0.6,0.6 -0.9,0.3 -1.6,-0.3 -1.71,-0.4 -1.5,0.4 -1.91,0.1 -0.9,0.5 -1.3,0.8 -1.1,0.3 -0.3,0.8 -1.1,0.3 -1.6,0.4 -0.6,1.4 -0.2,1.2 -0.8,0.4 -1,0.5 -0.7,0.9 -0.9,0.9 -1.5,0.3 -0.2,-1.1 -1.3,-0.1 -0.7,0.3 -0.3,0.7 -1.5,0.9 -1.91,0.2 -1.81,0.6 -1.71,0.4 -2.31,0.7 -2.21,0.8 -2.61,0.4 -2.21,0.2 -1.1,0.8 -1.71,-0.2 -0.8,-1.4 -0.7,-1.71 -1.4,-2.11 -1.4,-0.9 -0.7,-1.81 -1.1,-1.71 -1.3,-0.8 -1.71,-0.3 -2.71,0 -1.1,-1.2 -0.7,-1.4 -0.5,-1.3 -0.5,-2.11 -2.21,-2.01 -2.01,-0.7 -3.31,-0.3 -1.81,-1 -2.31,-0.7 -1.61,-0.8 -2.61,-2.21 -1.1,-1 -1.3,-0.7 -0.8,0 -1.5,0.4 -1.91,-0.5 -1.5,0 -1.81,-0.9 -0.2,-0.7 -1.2,-1.6 -0.8,-0.9 -1.3,0 -0.8,0.9 -1,0.1 -0.9,-0.6 -0.7,-0.5 -0.6,-0.7 -0.6,-0.9 -1.2,-0.5 -1.2,-1.3 -0.2,-1.2 -0.6,-1.4 -0.2,-1.3 -0.4,-0.8 0.1,-1.4 1.2,-0.3 2.31,-0.5 1.5,-0.9 0.9,-0.8 0.6,-1.5 3.31,-0.3 0.7,-0.7 0.4,-1.3 0.7,-0.7 1,0 2.21,0.6 1.6,1.2 2.01,0.6 2.71,1.4 3.41,1.3 3.41,1 3.61,0.7 1.91,1 1.2,0.9 2.01,0.7 0.4,0.8 0,1.6 1.91,1.71 2.31,1 1.5,0.4 3.81,0.5 1.46,1.24 z m 192.9,-16.84 3.51,1.3 2.01,1.71 1.81,1.2 1.71,1.2 2.11,1.6 2.01,2.31 1.6,0.8 1.91,0.7 1.4,1.2 1.3,1.3 1.5,0.8 1.1,0.4 1.1,1.4 0.1,2.01 1.3,1.6 1.4,1.6 0.5,1.33 1.71,2.41 0.6,1.81 0.1,3.91 -0.8,2.11 -0.9,1.5 -0.1,1.91 -1.1,1.71 -0.4,1.4 -0.4,2.71 -0.5,1.1 -0.6,1.5 -0.3,2.21 -0.2,2.81 -0.8,0.9 -0.4,2.51 -0.9,2.61 -0.7,2.01 -1.1,1.3 -0.6,0.9 -2.91,1 -2.01,0.9 -1.71,0.6 -1,-0.6 -2.31,-1 -2.11,-1 -1.5,-0.7 -1.6,0.4 -1.61,0.9 -2.71,0.8 -3.61,1.71 -2.91,1.6 -3.01,1.81 -2.81,1.3 -0.9,0.5 -3.11,0.8 -2.11,1.1 -0.4,1.6 -1.1,0.8 -0.8,0.6 -0.9,0.7 -1.61,1.81 -1.71,1.4 -1.2,0.2 -1.41,0.9 -1.4,0.5 -1.2,-0.9 -0.4,-1.3 -1,-0.8 -1,-0.3 -0.6,-1.61 -1.2,-0.5 -0.5,-0.8 -0.6,-1.4 -1.3,-1.61 -1.1,-0.9 -0.2,-2.21 -1.2,-0.4 0,-1.5 -1.6,-1.1 -1.91,-2.11 -2.01,-2.51 -1.2,-1.71 -1.2,-1.71 -1.1,-1.1 -1.71,0 -0.9,-1 0.2,-1 0.1,-1.86 -0.9,-1.91 -0.8,-1.3 -0.7,-1.1 -0.8,-1.3 -1.81,-1.81 -1.5,-1 -2.11,-0.6 -0.9,-2.11 -2.41,-0.6 -1.81,-0.6 -0.5,-1.2 -0.7,-1.71 -0.8,-0.6 -0.7,-0.6 1.6,-1.1 0.3,-0.9 0.5,-1.4 0.8,-2.01 1.1,-1.81 0.7,-1.3 0.8,-3.31 -0.7,-2.41 -0.8,-0.9 -1,-1.81 -0.8,-2.01 -0.5,-2.51 -0.4,-2.11 -0.3,-2.41 -0.6,-3.31 1.1,-1.2 1.1,-0.2 1.4,1 1.1,0.3 1.4,0.6 1.41,0.2 1.4,0 1.81,0 1.4,0.7 1.4,-0.2 1.5,-0.4 1.1,-0.3 1.4,-0.6 1.1,-1.3 1.91,-1.81 1.15,-0.68 0.8,-1 0,-1.56 0.9,-0.9 0.8,-0.7 0.5,-0.9 0.4,-1.2 0.9,-0.2 0.9,0.4 0.6,0.9 1,1.2 1.15,0.9 2.81,0.2 1,-0.7 1.3,0.3 1.3,1.3 1.1,0.2 1.81,0.3 1,1.3 1.2,0.2 1,-0.7 1,-1.81 0.8,-0.8 1.91,-1 0.4,-1.91 1.8,-0.8 2.21,0.3 1.2,0.2 1.1,0.9 1.81,0.6 2.41,0.5 1.91,0.7 2.71,0.6 1.91,1 3.53,1.73 z"
    },
    {
      "id": "SG-05", "title": "South West", "myColor": "#000", "myCheck": 'false', "d": "m 416.975,260.26064 0.017,0.0796 0,0 -0.017,-0.0796 z m -83.434,-22.94171 0.695,-0.0735 -0.041,0.73144 1.192,0.38487 0.057,0.63976 0.955,-0.22568 0.83,1.60091 6.826,1.08608 1.487,2.91268 -0.348,2.81293 -0.661,1.13545 2.388,1.05082 0.332,-0.35061 0.438,0.51785 0.757,-0.55916 1.293,1.17071 1.482,0.21964 0.336,0.47654 -0.225,0.56521 1.939,0.68913 -0.796,0.73547 3.627,-0.26296 -0.389,1.28557 0.694,1.2503 2.597,0.40602 1.534,-1.16869 0.964,0.21661 3.789,-2.11574 2.095,1.79334 -0.044,3.3187 1.783,1.21504 0.701,-0.16423 -0.025,0.96418 2.057,-1.05082 0.256,-0.88761 1.427,-0.36068 2.304,0.88559 -0.049,0.52692 1.174,-0.19243 0.525,0.6176 0.731,-0.67301 1.564,-0.0584 4.5,1.90417 0.598,0.96619 3.364,1.75405 0.716,-0.85335 1.425,0.46244 1.27,-0.53901 -0.049,-0.56419 0.799,-0.0826 0.06,-0.63774 1.729,-0.35867 0.619,-1.29363 0.564,0.0353 0.411,3.17563 1.489,1.08205 1.961,-0.16522 0.202,0.87249 0.975,0.0584 0.597,0.55211 0.584,-1.41049 2.046,-0.75664 2.918,1.39237 0.961,-0.2952 0.542,-0.9813 1.171,0.64681 0.685,-0.1078 0.488,-1.33091 1.234,0.76671 0.826,-1.17676 0.81,1.60394 1.357,0.60248 0.13,0.64379 0.674,0.002 0.097,-0.63473 1.261,-1.07097 0.183,-2.30011 0,0 0.822,0.57729 0.479,-0.6186 1.318,-0.34255 0.045,0.46043 -1.138,0.97929 0.309,0.43523 0.68,-0.0997 0.058,0.68208 0.814,0.59442 -0.784,0.65084 0.15,0.43524 0.627,-0.13601 0.509,0.63775 -1.625,1.69058 -1.461,0.67502 -1.563,1.80241 -0.678,-0.0463 -0.51,0.8604 -1.026,-0.25994 0.085,1.65028 -0.633,-0.0725 -0.142,0.3617 -0.381,-0.51483 -1.482,1.08608 -0.255,2.54393 -0.548,0.54405 0.399,0.94805 1.843,0.45942 -0.576,0.54002 0.568,0.32139 -0.252,1.04981 0.71,-0.0363 0.599,1.08709 1.834,0.79391 -0.272,1.25131 0.392,0.0927 -0.696,1.06794 0.308,1.16769 0.776,0.76268 -0.051,0.54405 -0.896,-0.13098 -0.42,-0.56319 -0.068,0.37983 -0.368,-0.19949 -0.013,-0.51583 -1.256,-0.26498 -0.566,0.74152 -0.414,-0.27202 -0.33,1.17575 -0.62,0.0191 -0.526,0.70625 -0.572,-0.2428 -0.466,0.91984 0.139,0.62868 0.484,0.13299 -0.102,0.92387 1.518,1.26844 -0.705,1.0075 0.29,0.81305 -1.027,-0.49267 0,0 -0.09,-0.59543 -1.581,-0.23676 -0.495,-1.24627 -1.616,-0.0292 -0.562,-0.85839 -0.684,0.40502 -0.161,1.14451 -1.219,-0.31434 0.297,0.75865 -0.482,0.50073 -0.011,1.07096 -1.682,-0.76166 -0.459,0.52087 -0.972,-0.41811 -0.678,3.10108 -0.849,-0.38386 -0.82,0.3768 -1.352,1.51125 0.237,3.20787 -0.149,0.62868 -0.765,0.0665 -0.752,0.76973 0.379,0.48058 -0.967,4.49545 -2.52,-0.83219 -0.67,1.29866 0.273,1.10422 -0.728,-0.65991 -0.456,0.38889 -0.368,-0.41005 -0.769,0.0846 0.115,-0.69014 -0.601,-0.58334 -0.55,0.0413 -0.403,0.97324 -1.323,0.35061 -1.37,-1.02563 -1.177,1.61602 -0.858,0.39897 -0.358,2.1369 -0.477,0.0715 -0.285,1.22612 -0.767,-0.24281 -1.357,-1.48606 -1.499,-0.42214 0.697,-1.07097 -0.176,-1.14754 0.394,-0.59543 -1.229,0.18941 -0.979,-0.82816 -0.469,0.61357 -1.291,-0.42416 -0.186,-2.34545 -0.793,-0.94906 -0.994,0.11485 0.241,-0.88357 -2.099,1.09615 -1.519,-1.57472 -2.104,0.0312 -0.848,-0.54808 -0.84,2.52277 -0.986,0.60853 0.317,2.42605 -1.845,-0.48662 -0.173,0.87249 -0.659,-10e-4 -0.388,0.93898 -0.666,-0.6045 -4.27,0.55413 -0.012,0.67905 -2.748,0.79189 0.392,0.76973 -1.674,1.15761 -0.502,-0.17429 0.224,-1.22411 -0.479,0.57024 -1.316,0.0665 -0.458,0.83521 -1.476,0.0887 -0.374,-2.08955 -0.958,0.23677 -0.037,-1.35912 -0.781,-0.41408 -2.437,1.68554 -0.433,1.44274 -1.796,-0.4292 -0.141,0.65387 -0.925,0.17732 0.083,0.8473 -0.669,1.20598 -0.817,-1.18784 -0.776,0.16724 0.106,-0.63976 -0.844,-0.70323 -0.97,-0.14105 -0.436,-0.63674 0.321,-0.17832 -0.779,-0.45237 0.021,-0.69014 0.674,-0.50677 -0.699,-1.45784 -0.497,0.0403 0.228,0.28411 -0.48,0.48763 -0.464,-0.51685 -0.366,0.41509 -0.611,-0.46546 -0.323,0.18941 0.134,0.84629 -0.695,-0.68912 -0.126,0.81808 -0.633,0.54002 -1.319,-3.01745 -1.142,-0.59442 -1.334,2.07846 -1.266,0.34658 -3.168,0.64379 -4.574,-0.50878 0,0 0.904,-2.28702 -0.918,-0.58838 0.339,-0.68107 -0.69,-0.56722 -0.019,-0.7395 -0.56,0.10478 -1.389,-1.17575 0.075,-1.12941 -0.762,-0.86745 -0.212,-3.23507 -0.538,-0.15818 0.82,-2.47542 -0.461,-1.32486 0.299,-0.40703 0.809,-0.18739 0.44,-0.9803 1.068,-0.0625 1.657,-1.52334 0.517,0.22064 1.219,-0.49568 0.583,-0.89265 0.812,-0.0776 -0.288,-0.16523 0.405,-0.41106 0.197,0.23072 0.596,-0.56723 0.616,0.52693 0.784,-0.53599 -0.104,-0.47957 0.921,-0.12292 -0.589,-0.67401 0.856,-0.18135 1.38,-1.97066 3.338,-1.83869 -0.144,-1.35105 0.519,-0.5773 1.126,-0.24683 0.965,0.64177 0.18,0.78585 1.731,0.18941 -0.042,-0.36371 0.732,0.1209 0.267,-1.69058 1.019,-0.0957 0.458,1.14552 0.982,-0.3496 0.829,0.85235 0.758,-0.15113 0.236,-0.9813 -0.094,0.78383 0.438,0.20452 0.069,-1.21907 1.569,0.1884 -0.629,-0.7526 0.412,-0.77879 -1.334,-1.01153 -0.618,0.0746 0.035,-1.01153 -2.205,-0.34255 -0.314,-0.90775 -1.191,-0.65286 -1.152,0.28814 -1.979,-1.2503 -0.745,0.21157 0.021,-0.7929 -1.595,-1.65934 -0.879,-0.0736 -0.647,-1.0619 -0.139,-2.23362 1.42,0.45538 0.704,-0.95208 0.97,0.37479 0.469,-1.66439 -0.217,-1.33291 -2.079,-0.24583 -1.278,-1.49916 -0.607,0.32441 -1.667,-0.36672 -0.002,-1.58983 1.263,0.22265 0.243,-0.54707 1.541,-0.27102 0.728,-1.31679 -0.016,-1.01455 3.986,1.02059 2.977,-0.65185 -0.255,-1.03369 -1.603,-0.30628 -0.578,-1.62006 -1.061,0.5632 -0.28,-0.2408 -0.196,-0.41307 0.579,-1.21303 -0.234,-1.2634 -0.667,-0.2015 -0.844,0.85738 -0.78,-0.4977 0.192,-0.75059 -0.842,-0.31131 -0.222,0.55714 -0.796,-0.34255 -0.091,-0.94402 -0.477,-0.2559 0.455,-0.45237 -0.122,-1.9485 -1.048,-0.56319 0.627,-0.63271 -1.702,0.0584 0.824,-2.53285 -0.509,-0.81708 -1.183,-0.57528 0.58,-1.05586 -0.188,-0.49972 -1.299,0.33348 -0.538,-0.27303 0.619,-0.66595 0,0 1.045,-0.78686 -0.694,-0.18034 -0.104,-0.86443 1.318,-0.49368 2.013,0.37278 1.427,-1.31982 0.048,-0.64682 0.423,0.0826 z"
    },
  ]
```

and fillColor() is my method to change the colors of specific path based upon conditions

```
fillColor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.myData.length; i++) {
      if (this.myData[i].title === 'Central Singapore') {
        this.myData[i].myCheck = 'true';
        console.log('hhhhhhhhh', this.myData);
      }
    }
  }
```

`What I need to do is if myFilteredArray is containing [{Central Singapore},{South West}] in the list then that part of SVG should turned its color.`

`myFilteredArray = [{Central Singapore},{South East}];`

**And myFilteredArray will be dynamic, it may contain anything in the list**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yout filtered should be an array of strings:

```
  myFilteredArray = ["Central Singapore","South East"];
```

Use:

```
  fillColor() {
    this.myData.forEach(x=>{
      x.class=this.myFilteredArray.indexOf(x.title)>=0?'red':'green'
    })
  }

<svg class="height-width" version="1.1" id="svg2" height="695.70178" width="611.85999"
        mapsvg:geoViewBox="68.184010 37.084109 97.418146 6.753659">
        <path class="select" *ngFor="let item of myData" [attr.d]="item.d" [attr.title]="item.title"
            [attr.id]="item.id" [attr.class]="item.class" />
</svg>
```

Note: declare an interface

```
export interface DataInterface{
  id:string;
  title:string;
  myColor:string;
  myCheck:string;
  d:string;
  class?:string;
}
```

And your data as

```
myData:DataInterface[] = [...}
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4fexf5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Hi Eliseo, thanks for your quick reply & solution, with the reference of your solution I've made one , but not working as expected! Would you please help me overthere? Below is the link I'm sharing of that stackblitz.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-feek7d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @SamruddhiDhaygude, should be:`this.myData[i].class=this.myData[i].myCheck === 'true' ? 'red' : 'green'`, but you can also in .html write:`[attr.class]="item.myCheck=='true'?'red':null"`. NOTE: for override the .css is possible you need use:`svg path.red {color:red}` and `svg path:hover, svg path.red:hover {  fill: #0096ff;  transition: 0.6m;}` [your forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xrdinv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: Thank you so very much @Eliseo :) , your solution worked well!

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect you'll need something like this:

```js
function fillColor(itemData) {
   switch (itemData.title) {
      case 'Central Singapore':
         return "special-red";  // return the class name 'special red' for central Singapore
      default:
         return "";
   }
}
```

```html
<svg class="height-width" version="1.1" id="svg2" height="695.70178" width="611.85999"
        mapsvg:geoViewBox="68.184010 37.084109 97.418146 6.753659">
        <path class="select" *ngFor="let item of myData" [attr.d]="item.d" [attr.title]="item.title"
            [attr.id]="item.id" [ngClass]="fillColor(item)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi @Paul, thank you so much for your quick reply, but somehow css is not applying by switchcase, it is not giving any errors but neither applying! I have added 'special-red' class in the css too.

Comment: @Paul, I think you should use ngClass instead of attr.class

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Fixed. Thanks.